# Login django automatically with provided http link with username and password

Tags: django

User gets an email with http link to django. I want to provide the username and password in the link so that the user automatically logges in.

```
http://www.test.com/username=testusername%password=testpassword
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: yes. Create url with username and password as variable and use variables to login

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def auto_login(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username')
    password = request.GET.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    login(request, user)
    
    return redirect('home')
    
    # else what you want
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/